# highlighting data values in a sql result set

Tags: php, mysql

I can think of a number of ways to do this in PHP or even JavaScript, but I'm wondering if there's a SQL-based technique I'm overlooking.

I have a database table, let's say 20 fields X 10 rows.  I want to display the entire table on an web page, so I'd do something like `SELCT * FROM data_table;`, and then format the result set using HTML table tags.

However, I'd also like to highlight values in the table based on whether they are the maximum or minimum value in their column.  For example, I'd add bold tags around the max in each column.  A resulting table might look something like this, with bold tags shown:

```
id |  field1  |  field2  |  field3  |  ...
0  |    5     |    2     | <b>7</b> |  ...
1  |    3     | <b>8</b> |    6     |  ...
2  | <b>9</b> |    5     |    1     |  ...
...
```

I could do a separate `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY` for each field and then interpret the results, but that seems like a lot of extra DB access.

My alternative right now is to just fetch the whole table, and then sort/search for the highlight values using PHP.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not pretty, but it will do exactly what you ask for:

```
SELECT
    (CASE field1
        WHEN (SELECT MAX(field1) FROM data_table)
        THEN CONCAT('<b>',field1,'</b>')
        ELSE field1
    END) as field1,
    (CASE field2
        WHEN (SELECT MAX(field2) FROM data_table)
        THEN CONCAT('<b>',field2,'</b>')
        ELSE field2
    END) as field2
FROM data_table
```

...repeat for other columns

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I hadn't considered that sort of query, but it looks good and definitely avoids having to make multiple queries.

Does it make sense to do this sort of thing in SQL vice post-processing it in PHP?

Comment: I'd say it would depend on the amount and complexity of the data. If your data is straight forward (e.g. all in one table), SQL would probably be the fastest option regardless of data quantity, at least when the tables in question are properly indexed. However, if the data is complex, SQL queries like this one with multiple sub queries could easily end up taking forever to complete. Then you might want to use SQL just to reduce that complexity, and then process the data in a separate process. I myself never use SQL to add HTML markup, but thats just me...

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think of:

```
$rowCount = 0;
$colorOne = '#ffffff';
$colorTwo = '#f3f3f3';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $rowColor = ($rowCount % 2) ? $colorOne : $colorTwo; 
        echo "<tag bgcolor='$rowColor'></tag>";
$rowCount++;
}
```